# why char * and char array behave differently in comparison?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here in my sample code, I am comparing two char pointer and two char array and output is

```
Output:
     case I :true
     case II : false
```

for case II, I understood that it's evaluated false because memory allocation of `arr1` and `arr2` is different. But I am not getting why case I evaluated as true.

```
int main()
    {
    char *string = {"string"};
    char *string2 = {"string"};

    char arr1[] = {"string"};
    char arr2[] = {"string"};

    /******* case I **********/
    if(string == string2){
      printf("case I :true \n");
     }
    else{
      printf("case I :false \n");
    } 

    /****** case II **********/
    if(arr1 == arr2){
      printf("case II : true \n");
     }
    else{
      printf("case II : false \n");
    }
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: First, you're not comparing strings, you're comparing pointers. Second, the first pair are pointers to constant literals, and your compiler is *likely* folding them into a single constant string in your read-only data segment, therefore *both* `string` and `string2` contain the same *address*.

Comment: Now I have to ask, the `char *string = {"string"};`, what does it mean, why does it compile, and does it compile without warnings?

Comment: @hyde it's compiling without any warning.

Comment: @Mat you are correct if I compile the code with -fwritable-strings then case I gives false. Now I understood that case I is true because of string pooling. thanks.

Comment: @hyde: Using braces for a scalar (such as a pointer) is permitted by C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.9: “The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.” I do not know why this is permitted but would hypothesize either it is historical (e.g., to accommodate compilers that permitted it before the language was standardized) or there is some case where automatic code generation is easier if braces are always used for the initializer, regardless of whether the object being initialized is a scalar or an aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr1` and `arr2` these two are pointers, so when you compair these two those pointers will be compaired which are never same. Thats why you get output `false`. Now about the first case:

When you write:

```
char *string = {"string"};
char *string2 = {"string"};
```

In memory compiler allocates space for your character sequence and stores a pointer to this area in `string` and `string2`. As a result both of this two are immutable.

If you do:

```
*(string)= 'a';
```

You'd get error.

String literals in C have static storage duration. They are never allocated "on the stack". They are always allocated in global/static memory, and remains as long as the program runs.

This is called [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) i.e. a method of storing only one copy of each distinct string value (as wikipedia says) and is an example of [Flyweight Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

More detail is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399682/c-optimisation-of-string-literals)

Comment: that I understood, I am trying to understand case I. I think that is related to string pooling.

Comment: if I compile the code with -fwritable-strings and write `string[0] = 'a'` then it won't crash and it changes the string to `atring`.

Comment: you know the thing from the original question. That's great.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(string == string2){
```

is comparing pointers not string. In first get it becomes true because both `string` and `string2` points to the same memory location and condition becomes `true`.
For string compare use library function `strcmp`. You will get right result.

Answer (score 0):

`arr1 == arr2` means that you are comparing address of first element of `arr1` and `arr2` .
so that why it giving `false` .

`char *string = {"string"};` "string" is constant and both `string` and `string1` points to same location thats why `string == string2` giving `true`

you should use `strcmp` to compare char's string .
operator `==` works with `string` in `c++`

Answer (score 0):

```
char *string = {"string"};
char *string2 = {"string"};
```

"string" in both *string and *string2 are string literals, same string literals share **same memory space**. That's why (string == string2) turns out to be true.